# the_post_thumbnail_url() causes fatal error with thumbnail support active

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I'm working on a child theme from twentythirteen.
Twentythirteen has support fro thumbnails:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

But when I use:

```
the_post_thumbnail_url()
```

I get a fatal error.
All the google answers say that **add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' )** has to be in the parent theme functions.php, well, in this case it is there but I'm getting the fatal error anyway.

I have even duplicated the support sentence in the child functions.php (just in case) but still in trouble with this.

The code:

```
        query_posts('category_name=curso&showposts=3');
        ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <h2>Cursos</h2>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class = "ficha curso">
        <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                    <div class="ficha-thumbnail" style = "background: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>') no-repeat; background-size: 300px auto"></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <h3 class="ficha-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>


                <div class="ficha-resumen">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Call to undefined function the_post_thumbnail_url()

Comment: I have this exact same error. `has_post_thumbnail()` returns TRUE and both `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` and `the_post_thumbnail_url()` result in `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Value of type null is not callable` yet somehow, strangely `get_the_post_thumbnail()` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Logic if it does anything for you:

```
        <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : 
                $imgURL = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()) );
        ?>
                <div class="ficha-thumbnail" style = "background: url('<?php echo $imgURL; ?>') no-repeat; background-size: 300px auto"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this does the trick for you... ;-)

Comment: Hi Poiz! The post has thumbnail and the has_post_thumbnail returns it. This the strange thing, as the function to get the thumbnail url doesn't work, and it should.

Comment: OK.... Would you mind **commenting out the IF Clause associated with the thumbnail** to see if the other Data like **the_title(), the_excerpt()** makes it through...? In other words; ***without the Thumbnail, does the Title and the Excerpt render normally?***

Comment: Yes, everything renders fine.
I'm afraid it is going to be a stupid mistake I'm falling into, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Great... we are clear on one point. Next up: **Is this Thumbnail associated with a CUSTOM POST-TYPE or just the standard Wordpress Post?** The reason is that ***if the Thumbnail is associated with a Custom Post-Type, You MUST enable the Support for Thumbnails on the Custom Post-Type Definition Code.*** And even if you did it on the Theme, it has no effect on a Plugin or Custom Post-Type so long as its Support Thumbnail is False.

Comment: It is a normal post. The question is: if I can see the thumbnail with the_post_thumbnail() why I can't get the url with the_post_thumbnail_url()?

Comment: All fine till here: why not just simply try ***(only for testing purposes)*** something like: **$tNail = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID()); var_dump($tNail); exit;** to see what you get?

Comment: I get this (I guess is the url): string(188)

Comment: Voila... If you got a URL String back, then **You are off to a very great Start: Bravo!!!** You can then build your image based-off of this String like **... style='background:'<?php echo $imgURL; ?>'** where $imgURL is the Result of the function. To get a larger thumbnail you may use: **$imgURL = get_the_post_thumbnail ( get_the ID(), 'large');** but if you got the HTML Content for the image; you can use it directly. Keep me posted... ;-)

Comment: I have thought already about that possibility but the string contains more info, not only the source but also width, height, and also the <img> tag, so I will have to clean the string and extract the src part...
It will work anyway...

Comment: Try the updated code above... it should be able to do the trick for you... Let me know how it went...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111574/discussion-between-user997593-and-poiz).

Answer (score 1):

With the excellent help of Poiz I have finally found a solution. The one suggested by him works, but I needed to get the large thumbnail rather than the attachment.
This is doing the trick for me:

```
<?
if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : 
$imgURL = the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'large');
preg_match('/src="([^"]+)/i',$imgURL, $src);
?>
<div class="ficha-thumbnail" style = "background: url('<?php echo $src; ?>') no-repeat; background-size: 300px auto">
```

I will mark Poiz answer as the correct one as he deserves the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing single quotation marks around php tags in your markup? It seems like these are the source of a parsing problem.

```
background: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>)
```

Comment: Hi Ewa, this doesn't seem to affect the parsing, not under my server conditions. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You might like this simple function to do the job.

```
function getImage($id, $size){
    if(has_post_thumbnail()){
        return wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($id), $size)[0];
    }
    return false;
}
```

It checks if there is a post thumbnail, if there is it looks for the post thumbnail ID, and then using the $size and wp_get_attachement_image_src's first part of the answer (the src) the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve the post featured image url with the following:

```
wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
```